# How to allow AWS CodeBuild to modify specified role in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

CodeBuild console has an "**Allow AWS CodeBuild to modify this service role so it can be used with this build project**" checkbox that we can select or clear it when create/update a CodeBuild project.

In case of creating a CodeBuild project by CloudFormation template, how can I define that option?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I define that option?

You can't. You have to provide valid role yourself. What you see is AWS Console specific and the console does a lot of "magic" in the backend to simplify things.

When you use CloudFormation, you have to create everything yourself.